# How to make reusable workflow branch aware

Tags: github, github-actions

I am triggering a workflow only if another workflow ran successfully. This causes the triggered workflow to not have the branch context of the successful branch. Therefore the workflow file used is always the default branch once instead of the pushing branch.

For best-practices reasons I want to split the CI and CD in two parts, or workflows.

1. `ci.yml` (Building and testing Bosap) --> installs, lints and tests the program
2. `cd.yml` (Distribute bosap) --> distributes the whl files to targets depending on branch

Now I only want to trigger the `cd.yml` if the `ci.yml` was successful, therefore the cd runs on:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Building and testing Bosap"]
    types: [completed]
    branches:
      - 'develop'
      - 'dev-*'
      - 'feat-*'
      - 'bug-*'
      - 'fix-*'
    tags:
jobs:
  on-ci-success:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
```

which works well, however with using `workflow_run` I am losing the branch context:

[image]

I can work around this by checking out the branch with reference to the workflow_run hear_branch:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
            ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - run: echo "CI pipeline was successful"
      - run: echo "Context branch is ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}"
```

Problem is that the used `cd.yml` would still always be the default branch `cd.yml`, because the checkout only happens after the trigger of `cd.yml` workflow. As seen by the missing `fix-cd` branch tag in the image above. So I can only adapt and test changes to the `cd.yml` by merging them into the default branch.

Is there a way to fix this and making the `workflow_run` "branch aware"? I am not far from just using one big YAML file, because the downsites of having a workflow trigger another just seem to be too many. Maybe I also just did a general mistake concept-wise and this should be structured completely differently.

Comment: This would be substantially easier if you made `cd.yml` a reusable workflow with a `workflow_call`, rather than the side-effect-y `workflow_run` trigger, then just called it as needed _from_ `ci.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the push into the direction I needed. I was so focused on getting this to work that I search more and more into the wrong direction. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @jonrsharpe I changed to a "push" instead of a "pull" approach and now trigger the cd.yml from the ci.yml

```
Start-Distribute-workflow:
  # Only if CI was successful
  needs: [Prepare-Test-Build]
  # Only if wheel file was build (not the case for certain branches)
  if: needs.Prepare-Test-Build.outputs.BUILD_VERSION != ''
  uses: ./.github/workflows/cd.yml
  # Pass
  with:
    build_version : ${{ needs.Prepare-Test-Build.outputs.BUILD_VERSION }}
```

The BUILD_VERSION is an output of the previous jon Prepare-Test-Build.
Works like a charm now. Thank you